# Strip integers from a row with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe with  column A, number/invoice number and i wish to create a new column C by stripping off the number only which is a 6 digit number often starting with 2, i can achieve that by stripping the first 6 digits using df['C'] = df['A'].str[6:] but often times there a cases where it interchanges as invoice number/number and in that case my result would be wrong, i need help fixing this. my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['208953/2005016337RRH', '209265/03983RH', '00468RH/209408', '209664/2076585rrh'], 'B' : ['208953', '108953', '347', '209664']})

df['C'] = df['A'].str[:6]
```

this wont work cos i would get some correct and some wrong numbers.

Comment: This code will not run, have you tried running this yourself?

Comment: it works but will give incorrect result when the format of the row is interchanged. it should always be in the format 208953/2005016337RRH but sometimes there can be a data entry error and it would be entered as 2005016337RRH/208953 if that happens my code would be wrong as i would need 208953

Comment: This code cannot run, it is impossible.  Try to copy/paste what you just shared with us and run it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` on "/" and keep only the part that has 6 characters:

```
splitA = df["A"].str.split("/", expand=True)
df["C"] = splitA[0].where(splitA[0].str.len()==6, splitA[1])

>>> df
                      A       B       C
0  208953/2005016337RRH  208953  208953
1        209265/03983RH  108953  209265
2        00468RH/209408     347  209408
3     209664/2076585rrh  209664  209664
4   200501633721/208953  208953  208953
```

Comment: thanks but would this also work in a cast where they are both integers, i mean the number/invoice number e.g 200501633721/208953, because they would both be integers

Comment: No - if you want to filter on the length of the string being 6 characters, I can update the code

Comment: please do, that would help.

Comment: @dataguy - Edited. That will work with the case you provided. See the last row of the output.

Comment: apologies on the back and forth I just found a case where the correct number had strings attached to the back e.g 16337206983/208953RRH became 208953RRH the first 6 digits are correct but I just need the RRH removed. Asides that the solution works, please help handle the last part.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question - the current question (in the state that it was first posted) was answered. You probably need a regular expression for cases where this fails. This is also why a minimum reproducible example with all possible edge cases is always useful.

Comment: For example if you have "004688/208953RH", it is unclear which 6-digit number you want to keep. Explain all this in your new post if you create one.

Comment: ok thanks i figured it out already. i just extracted the 6 digits from your result for those having strings.